# Moving an element inside a div down a few pixels

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my navigation bar I have two elements inside a div, a picture and some text. I want to move the text down a few pixels. This would normally be pretty easy, however, the text simply isn't budging. When I put a top padding on the containing div both elements move down. I just want the text to move down only, and the image to stay in the same place. Here's my code:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
        <img src="{{asset('/images/navbar/banner.png')}}" class="banner">
        <a class="text-white hover-white" id="title" href="/">MY WEBSITE'S TITLE</a>                            
    </div>
```

I want to move the  down a few pixels without effecting the image

Comment: I do not know if this will help, but I have noticed that you missing the close tag of one div

Comment: #title{margin-top:10px;} ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to align the text with the bottom of the image you can use

```
a {
   vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Example:

```css
a {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" class="banner">
    <a class="text-white hover-white" id="title" href="/">MY WEBSITE'S TITLE</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your `a` tag with this:

```
<a class="text-white hover-white" id="title" href="/" style="padding-top: 3px; position: absolute">MY WEBSITE'S TITLE</a>
```

this will add 3px of padding to the top of the text.

Answer (score 0):

well you may use **line-height** Property for text 
for example :

```
a {
   line-height:25px;
  }
```